# trying to subtract binary numbers with java program small error

Tags: java, binary, calculator

im making a simple add and subtract binary calculator. i got it to take in a number and convert it into binary number, and i even got it to add the numbers. When i try and get it to subtract it doesnt work. i get a weird output. heres the piece of the code.

```
int [ ] subtarctBin = new int [16];
int carryX = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    subtarctBin[i] = 0;
}
for (int i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
{
    int subtract = resultBinA[i] - resultBinB[i] - carryX;
    subtarctBin[i] = subtract % 2;
    carryX = subtract / 2;

}
System.out.println("");
System.out.print("DIF:");
for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
{
    System.out.print(subtarctBin[i]);
}   
 }
```

Comment: Where's the weird output that goes with this code?

Comment: DIF:000000000000001-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Ken Y-N's answer, I find that in this statement, you are subtracting the first digit from the second along with the carryX.

```
  int subtract = resultBinA[i] - resultBinB[i] - carryX;
```

I think you should ensure that the first number is the bigger of the two( i.e. resultBinB > resultBinA) and then the subtraction should go like this instead:

```
  int subtract =  (resultBinB[i] + carryX) - resultBinA[i];
```

Comment: That works to stop getting a negative `subtract`, but we need extra code to calculate the next `carryX`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `resultBinA` and `resultBinB` contain the binary numbers, the problem is here:

```
subtarctBin[i] = subtract % 2;
```

According to the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.17.3), `the result of the remainder operation can be negative only if the dividend is negative, and can be positive only if the dividend is positive`. So, when `subtract` equals -1, `subtract % 2` also equals -1, so `subtarctBin[i]` will be -1 too, which is not what you want.

Furthermore, `subtract / 2` will yield 0 when `subtract` equals -1, as `Integer division rounds toward 0`, as [noted here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.17.2).

Now, to solve your problem, build up this table:

```
resultBinA resultBinB carryX subtract required subtarctBin required new carryX
         0          0      0        0                    0                   0
         0          0      1       -1                    1                   1
         0          1      0       -1                    1                   1
         0          1      1       -2                    0                   1
         1          0      0        1                    1                   0
         1          0      1        0                    0                   0
         1          1      0        0                    0                   0
         1          1      1       -1                    1                   1
```

So, we can see, I hope, that:

```
subtarctBin[i] = (subtract + 2) % 2;
carryX = (subtract < 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Gives you the results you require.

Comment: hmm that makes sense, but im still struggling on how to fix it, im sorry im kinda slow at this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ((resultBinA[i] - resultBinB[i]) < 0 ){
    int k = i-1;
    while (resultBinA[k] != 1){
        resultBinA[k] = 1;
        k--;
        }
    resultBinA[k] = 0;
    subract = 1;
    }
else{
    subract = (resultBinA[i] - resultBinB[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a small hack.

Try to write a function to subtract a binary number by 1.

Then, make another function to check if a binary number is equal to 0 (basically, if we have a String like "010100" we need to check if each character is 0).

In your main function, keep subtracting until one of your numbers is 0. Return whichever is not 0. (Or return 0 if both numbers are 0.)

```
public String sub(String bin2){
        while(!iszero(bin1) && !iszero(bin2)){
            bin1 = subby1(bin1);
            bin2 = subby1(bin2);
        }




        if(!iszero(bin1))
            return bin1;
        else
            return bin2;
    }


    private String subby1(String bin){
        int index = bin.length()-1;

        while(bin.charAt(index) != '1'){
            index--;


        }
        char[] c = bin.toCharArray();
        c[index] = '0';
        for(int x = bin.length()-1; x >= index + 1; x--){
            c[x] = '1';
        }


        return String.valueOf(c);


    }

    private boolean iszero(String bin){
        for(int x = 0; x < bin.length(); x++)
            if(bin.charAt(x) == '1')
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```